# Trouble understanding where to register fields

Tags: field, laravel-nova

I am installing this Nova package: https://novapackages.com/packages/classic-o/nova-media-library and am having trouble figuring out where to put this block of code:

Add field to the resource:

```
use ClassicO\NovaMediaLibrary\MediaLibrary;

class Post extends Resource
{
    ...
     public function fields(Request $request)
        {
            return [
                ...
                MediaLibrary::make('Image'),
                ...
            ];
        }
    ...
}
```

I've looked around, but am very new to Laravel, so I'm just a little confused. I understand that it is a field, so I've looked here: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#place-field, but don't really understand the location where these can be registered.

I appreciate any insight or context here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Laravel Nova, they tried to make everything as easy as possible. So, a `Resource` is what adds all the functionality to your `Model`, and a `Model` represents (in some way) a table in your database. A resource is just a class that extends from `Resource`, and has some functions to be completely functional.

So, in your example, you should have a `Model` called `Post`, the code showing is an incomplete `Resource` called `Post` (that's why you se those three points before and after the function). As you read the `Resource` documentation, you will see that the function `fields()` always returns an array of `Fields`. The code

```
MediaLibrary::make('Image')
```

is, indeed, a field, that's why it's inside de array. The code that you have is just an example, and it's purpose is to illustrate that the `MediaLibrary` field can be used as any other field. I strongly recommend that you take enough time to read about [Models, Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes), [Resources](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/#defining-resources) and [Fields](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I’m spending this eve rereading the docs again.